# Not able to delete emails from Outlook at first shot

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I built a console application in Visual Studio with C#. I have a configuration file (app.config) with a lot of keys in order to identify the email I want to delete.

My issue is that even if the delete works if I have 10 unread emails to Delete, I need to run the application a few times in order to be able to do that. I am not getting any error.

It looks like there is a kind of timeout, so the application deletes the first 3 emails, leaving untouched the rest, then I run the application again and it removes the next 3 or 4 emails and then over and over until I get everything deleted.

Am I doing something wrong? Following my code, it connects to Outlook and our mail server is Microsoft Exchange.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Exception = System.Exception;

namespace OutlookReader
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main()
     {
        try
        {
            var outlookApplication = new ApplicationClass();
            var mapiNameSpace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            //Inbox
            var inbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            //Unread emails
            var unreadItems = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");

            var splitter = char.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitter"]);
            var excludeBySenderName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeBySenderName"].Split(splitter).ToList();
            var excludeByEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeByEmail"].Split(splitter).ToList();
            var excludeByDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeByDomain"].Split(splitter).ToList();
            var excludeByTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeByTo"].Split(splitter).ToList();
            var excludeBySubject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeBySubject"].Split(splitter).ToList();



            foreach (MailItem item in unreadItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sender: " + item.SenderName + " - To: " + item.To + " - Subject: " + item.Subject);

                if (stringExists(item.SenderName, excludeBySenderName) 
                    || stringExists(item.SenderEmailAddress, excludeByEmail) 
                    || stringExists(item.SenderEmailAddress, excludeByDomain) 
                    || stringExists(item.To, excludeByTo) 
                    || stringExistsFullSearch(item.Body, excludeByDomain) 
                    || stringExistsFullSearch(item.HTMLBody, excludeByDomain)  
                    || stringExistsFullSearch(item.Subject, excludeBySubject)) 
                {
                    //item.UnRead = false;
                    item.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool stringExists(string pattern, List<string> list)
    {
        var result = list.Find(item => item.ToLower().Contains(pattern.ToLower()));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool stringExistsFullSearch(string pattern, List<string> list)
    {
        var result = false;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (pattern.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower()))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the collection while you are iterating through its elements. Loop through the restricted items colelction and store the entry ids `(MailItem.EntryID`) in a list.  You can then loop through the stings in that list, open each item using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`, then delete the message using `MailItem.Delete`.